# Add input message via data validation to all cells that are selected

Tags: excel, vba

I expect an Input Message with a title when a cell is clicked.

I can't achieve this with the VBA code that I have.

```
Sub SelectAllNonBlankCells()
    Dim objUsedRange As Range
    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim objNonblankRange As Range

    Set objUsedRange = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    For Each objRange In objUsedRange
        If Not (objRange.Value = "") Then
           If objNonblankRange Is Nothing Then
              Set objNonblankRange = objRange
           Else
              Set objNonblankRange = Application.Union(objNonblankRange, objRange)
           End If
        End If
    Next

    With objNonblankRange.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="="""
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InputTitle = "Title"
        .InputMessage = "Enter message"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What result are you getting? Have you tried stepping through your code with F8 and looking at the variable values? Some `Debug.Print` statements might also help. Please note that `.UsedRange` is not the most reliable way to find the used range.

Comment: Hm, it seems as though you are interested in non-empty cells. There is a `Range` object method called `SpecialCells`. When you use the `xlCellTypeConstants` enumeration you will end up with a `Range` holding all non-empty cells. So no need to loop through all cells in your `objUsedRange`. Also, as per @M.Schalk, using `UsedRange` is not reliable, neither is using `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: *expecting an Input Message with a title when a cell is clicked.* The code you have now is a macro loop that has to be called. What you describe is a `selection_change` event when you select a cell. [Try looking here](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-events/#Workbook-SelectionChange-Event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this one you should capture `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.
Try this procedure:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim objUsedRange As Range
Dim objNonblankRange As Range

Set objUsedRange = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Selection.Value = "" Then
         If objNonblankRange Is Nothing Then
             Set objNonblankRange = Selection
         Else
             Set objNonblankRange = Application.Union(objNonblankRange, Selection)
         End If
    With objNonblankRange.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="="""""
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InputTitle = "Title"
        .InputMessage = "Enter message"
    End With
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

This one should be added to the sheet in order to work so, right-click on the Datasheet tab and chose "Show code". Copy on there.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing two double-quote marks. so the line should look like:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="="""""
```

That's assuming that you expect the validated fields to be empty.  As quotemark is a special character you need to put it twice to be intepreted as string.

If you do not want to validate anything, but just add the input message you can use a condition like:

```
 .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, Formula1:="=(1=1)"
```